# Magento 2.4.x website product page GSI score

Tags: magento2, performance, pagespeed, fotorama, speedoptimization

we are facing a challenge with the Google PSI optimization score for the product page :

1. Scores on the desktop are above 85.
2. We have reduced considerable JS payload
3. Using advanced JS bundle
4. Most JS is moved to the footer.
5. We use Varnish
6. CDN too is in place
7. product image size is less than 30 kb
8. We have removed fotorama js from the bundle to reduce LCP delays and there is a slight improvement but still not enough score going above 45 for mobile devices.

We can get Google PSI scores of above 70 on Shopify but cant achieve on Magento 2.

Challenge: LCP is high on the product page.
Reason: Fotorama JS calls image so this is loaded later and not via simple HTML call.

A higher LCP is resulting in scores going down.

The client doesn't want to customize the product page and use a custom solution.

Advice on what should be done.

Comment: Js  Bundle may cause issue. Here is detais about it
JS bundling saves page size in MBs but bundled js loaded synchronously. And the browser waits for js download completion.

But in JS Merge Magento merges only those js which are required synchronously. And browser only waits for merged JS which is much lighter than bundled one. And rest of the JS loaded asynchronously.

Somewhere I have seen it is better to load js asynchronously if using HTTP2. And Google also recommends deferring JS.

Comment: Its not normal JS bundle that comes with Magento but advance JS bundle that should be considered. RequireJS will handle most of the JS downloads.when we add script of JS in our code we shall clearly specify our JS  dependency.